# server side in shiny not responding while calling web call

Tags: r, web-applications, shiny, reactive-programming

I am working on a shiny application, when a url is provided in the UI, i need to fetch and download a file from web.

On server site when i am trying to fetch and download the file to a specific location, the application is giving error. I guess its because of reactive procedure.

A sample code is provided below, Please let me know where i am wrong.

server side:
{

```
library(shiny)
require(XML)
require(utils)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

dfile <- "~/dest/temp.pdf"
dest <- "~/dest"
url<-input$pdfurl

download.file(url,dfile)

myfiles <- list.files(path = dest, pattern = "pdf",  full.names = TRUE)

lapply(myfiles, function(i)    system(paste('"D:/pranav/software/xpdf/bin64/pdftotext.exe"', paste0('"', i, '"')), wait = FALSE) )
```

}

client side:

{

```
library(shiny)

row <- function(...) {
  tags$div(class="row", ...)
}

col <- function(width, ...) {
  tags$div(class=paste0("span", width), ...)
}

shinyUI(fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
          column(12,style = "background-color:#ADD8C9;",
                 titlePanel("Document Reader"),
        fluidRow(
          column(8,style = "background-color:#ADD8C6;", 
                 tags$div(
                   class = "container",

                   row(
                     col(3, textInput("pdfurl", "PDF URL"))
                   ),
                   row(
                     col(6, style = "width:600px;",htmlOutput('pdfviewer'))
                   )
                 )
          ),

          column(4,style = "background-color:#ADD8C9;", 

          )

        )


      )
      )
)
)
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shiny works throught reactivity. You can read more about that on http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html

Can't reproduce your problem without the `ui-side`, but you can try something like this:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$pdfurl, {
        download.file(input$pdfurl,dfile)
        myfiles <- list.files(path = dest, pattern = "pdf",  full.names = TRUE)
        lapply(myfiles, function(i)    system(paste('"D:/pranav/software/xpdf/bin64/pdftotext.exe"', paste0('"', i, '"')), wait = FALSE) )
    })
}
```